# how to connect a lambda function (behind an api gateway) to a private rds in a vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have the following AWS VPC configuration:

- 2 public subnets
- 2 private subnets

**Cloudfront** is in front of the `load balancer`. The `load balancer` is linked to the `public subnets` and my **RDS database** reside in the `private subnets`.

What i want to accomplish is:

- Create an **API Gateway (publicly accessible)** but restricted to only a specific IP address that can access it. The `API Gateway` is connected to a `lambda function` that, when called/triggered, the function must update some table data of my (private) RDS Postgres instance.

From my understanding the first step would be to create an IAM role for the lambda function to be only accessible by the IP address mentioned above.

Now what is the best way to access a private RDS from that lambda connected to API Gateway? Especially without using Nat Gateway because of the crazy cost associated to it.

Can someone help me just figure out how to do it, i am referring to the high level understanding how to do it?

Comment: In terms of restricting by specific IP addresses, this would be most easily achieved using a resource policy (REST API - not sure if this is possible with an HTTP API). In terms of access for the Lambda, you would ensure that the Lambda is deployed into a VPC and subnet that has access to the RDS database (most logically, the same private subnet as the database instance).

Comment: @Norman thank you for the feedback. what would be the best for `api gateway` to communicate with the lambda function, since the lambda function will reside inside a private subnet, which means no access to internet...i would assume, any thoughts?

Comment: It is fine for the API Gateway to proxy to a Lambda within a VPC.  I have implemented this integration myself in previous projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Norman said in their comment, you can control access to your API in API Gateway, and limit it to certain IP addresses, with [API Gateway Resource Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies.html). This will at the same time control access to your Lambda that's behind that API.

You can then edit the Lambdas `Configuration -> VPC` setting and add it to a subnet that has access to your RDS database (and put it either in the same subnet as the database, or another subnet that has access permissions to the RDS subnet). To connect your Lambda to a VPC, the Lambda execution role will need the following permissions

```
ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
```

They are for example included in the managed policy  `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole`. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html) you can read more about configuring a Lambda for VPC access.